# Is it okay to seek website recommendation?

Tags: discussion

I need the data for a specific watchable astronomical event. But until today I couldn't find the data I want. Is it okay to ask users here if they know the source(s) of the data I need (website, book, article, etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guidance for the tag [resource-request](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) (**78** questions) is:

> Questions asking "What is a good book about X?" or more generally, "What should I read to learn about X?", typically where there is not a single authoritative reference. Also requests for multimedia, like video lectures.

It doesn't specifically say "websites" there are many resource requests who's answers are websites, and there are certainly several explitic website requests which are well received and answered, just for example:

- [Is there a website that shows equivalent views through different telescopes?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36886/7982)
- [Is there a website out there where I can find/compare data on stellar parameters for the brightest stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/38990/7982)
- [Is there any site with telescopes data?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33477/7982)

and the community wiki answer to our canonical

- [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982)

is choc-full of websites.

So I would say

###Yes, absolutely!

Just make sure it's a good Stack Exchange question, and include some evidence that you've tried and failed, or what you found is inefficient in some way.

No "please find a site for me, I'm too busy to look" questions please!